# String validation with regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need a help to frame a regex to validate a string format in Javascript,

Total length of the string should be between 3 and 30 characters length. First character must be strictly an alphabet. Subsequent characters can be either alphabet or dot or space. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will work for you.

```
var re = /^[a-z][a-z. ]{2,29}$/i
```

Regular expression:

```
^                # the beginning of the string
 [a-z]           # any character of: 'a' to 'z'
 [a-z. ]{2,29}   # any character of: 'a' to 'z', '.', ' ' (between 2 and 29 times)
$                # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: `\s` will match tabs and newlines. Should use an explicit space.

Comment: Simple and efficient +1 :)

Comment: `What's going on?` Just sent my letter to Regex Santa in the chat room, might see you there? Off to feed the neighbor's cat for a mo.

Comment: Gotta love race conditions :-)